# How to assign boolean value to appdelegate method from view controller

Tags: ios, swift

I am new to IOS and swift. Does anyone know how to assign value to boolean appdelegate method?  I want to set shouldAllowExtensionPointIdentifier in **viewcontroller** but i didn't find any solution. Thank you

```
    //
//  AppDelegate.swift
//  TestKeyboard
//
//  Created by Mol Monyneath on 11/1/17.

import UIKit

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?

   public var Alow : Bool?

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch     
        return true
    }
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, shouldAllowExtensionPointIdentifier extensionPointIdentifier: UIApplicationExtensionPointIdentifier) -> Bool {

          print("\(extensionPointIdentifier.rawValue) allow =  \(Alow)")
            return Alow!

   }
}
```

Here is Main view controller:
I couldn't block that app . please help

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController,UITextFieldDelegate {
    @IBOutlet weak var normaltextView: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var txtView: UITextField!
    var appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        normaltextView.delegate = self
        txtView.delegate = self 
    }

    func textFieldShouldBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {   
        let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
        if textField.keyboardType == UIKeyboardType.numberPad{
           // textField.inputView = nil
            txtView.inputView = nil
            appDelegate.Alow = false
            txtView.reloadInputViews()

            print("false")

        }else{
            print("should Press")
            print("True")
          //  textField.inputView = nil
            appDelegate.Alow = true
            txtView.reloadInputViews()
            normaltextView.reloadInputViews()
        }  
        return true
    }        
}
```

thank

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?  `shouldAllowExtensionPointIdentifier` is a delegate method that iOS will call to check whether custom keyboards are permitted.  It isn't a boolean value; it is a function that returns a boolean value

Comment: Sorry bro. all i want is to call shouldAllowExtensionPointIdentifier from viewcontroller. I can't find any solution on internet. thank @Paulw11

Comment: But why would you want to call it?  The operating system will call it. I mean you *can* call it by getting the App delegate instance using `UIApplication.shared.delegate`, but calling it won’t do anything.

Comment: i want to disable external keyboard when ever click on number text field and    enable it back when ever user click on other . so what i have to do?

Comment: You can’t, but that isn’t what that delegate method does anyway. It prevents or allows the use of custom keyboards provided by other apps in your app.

Comment: so what if i want to force user to use original keyboard when they click on number textfield ? do we have any solution? @Paulw11 Thanks

Comment: You can return `false` from that method to disable 3rd party keyboards entirely

Comment: i just add some more detail on the top. please help check my code . thank you @Paulw11

Comment: Your `shouldAllowExtensionPointIdentifier` function should just return `false` if you want to disable keyboard extensions.  What problem are you seeing that you are trying to fix?  Be aware if you are testing on an iPad that `UIKeyboardType.numberPad` is only respected on an iPhone; on an iPad you will see the standard, full, keyboard

Comment: but some case i want it to allow . i have 2 textview. 1 is written in Khmer language, one more is writing in english number, so when it in number textfield i want it to automatically change to english keyboard.

Comment: That still isn't the purpose of the delegate method you are referring to; that method simply prevents or allows using 3rd party keyboards with your app. There is no way to specify that a particular national keyboard is used for an input element in your app; the user needs to select the keyboard they want to use from the keyboard itself using the   key